# `eval()`ing code with JSX syntax in it

Tags: reactjs

I have a website where the server is generating some javascript and sending it via ajax to the client. The problem is, I want to use React on the pages but don't know which function to call. Right now the javascript is in jQuery and I use eval() to execute the javascript on the client side. What is the React equivalent of eval() that works for JSX.

Comment: See here - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#getting-started -  you'll want to use `<script type="text/babel">` if you want to embed React components directly into an existing page.

Comment: You should precompile the content rather than require a client to download a large and complex compiler, compile, and then show content. This is especially true if the page might be used on mobile clients.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want it to work with JSX, you can transpile the code with something like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) before you execute it.

For example, when using [the browser version](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/) of Babel:

```
var jsCode = babel.transform(jsxCode);
eval(jsCode.code);
```

There's also a `run` method you can use to simply execute the code:

```
babel.run(code);
```

Both `transform` and `run` take an optional `options` hash; check [the documentation](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) for more details.

Of course, as is standard, [be careful with `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#dont-use-it).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.