# Passing code block as a prop to add to an array

Tags: reactjs

I have a very niche issue where I am trying to pass a block of executable code as a prop `options`. The prop looks like this...

```
columns={[
    {
        name: "Fund Name",    //Title
        width: "40%",         //Colum Width
        options: {[           
            var splitValue = value.split("//");
            return (
                <div className="fundName">{splitValue[0]}<p>{splitValue[1]}</p></div>
            );
        ]}
    }, {
        name: "Review Date",
        width: "20%"
    }, {
        name: "Company Debt",
        width: "20%"
    }, {
        name: "Alerts",
        width: "10%",
        options: {[
            return <Alerts {data: value} />
        ]}
    }
}
```

So sometimes there are some variables and additional code and sometimes it may just be returning a component. Anyway. I need the code to look like this in the component...

```
const columns = [{
    name: "Fund Name",
    options: {
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
            var splitValue = value.split("//");
            return (
                <div className="fundName">{splitValue[0]}<p>{splitValue[1]}</p></div>
            );
        }
    }
}, {
    name: "Review Date"
}, {
    name: "Company Debt"
}, {
    customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
        return <Alerts {data: value} />
    }
}];
```

So firstly. Is this possible? can I pass variables like the splitValue, and, will it pick up that the passed in "value" variable is to be associated with the `customBodyRender: (value,....` variable?

Here is my attempt but it is throwing a lot of errors. I feel I may be close if it even at all possible....

```
let columns = this.props.columns.map(item =>
    item.options
    ? ({ ...item, options: { customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => { eval(item.options) }} })
    : item
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use code **directly** in data structures because there is simply no syntax for this (in js generally) and ...

> "The argument of the eval() function is a string."

Write code as strings? OK, you can. Problem here? JSX is transpiled into normal Javascript code (using bable). `eval` won't do that.

Is it possible to use JSX from running code with eval? Yes, you can using [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33227697/6124657) or other libs.

Of course **using/storing functions is a preferred (safer) way for this kind of jobs**.